# Unable to get data from multiple tables based on some comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

This is what I am trying to do :

```
select StudentId,StudentName from Student where StudentId in (
select StudentId from Student_Course_Mapping where Grade > (
select AVG(Grade) from [dbo].[Student_Course_Mapping]))
```

But here I am confused with comparing 2 grades and den getting the required result so I am kinda stuck here.

Can someone please help me with this ?

Comment: Sample data along with the expected output will help to get the answers faster.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you need. Let us if any issue

```
    Select SCM.StudentId,S.STUDENTNAME,SCM.grade,SA.Avg_Grade,SCM.OfferId from 
    Student_Course_Mapping SCM join
    (
    select avg(Grade) as Avg_Grade,OfferId from Student_Course_Mapping s group 
    by offerId 
    ) SA
    On SCM.OfferId=SA.Offerid
    join Student S
    On S.studentId=SCM.studentid
    where SCM.grade>SA.Avg_Grade
```

You can remove unwanted columns in query it is provided just for understanding.

Comment: And if you need to add course name also in the quey you need to join CoursesOffered and Course table also.